# Error defining variable

Tags: python-2.7

I am creating a basic program in python which sees a player verses an AI in a game of tic tac toe.  The issue I am having is that the variable I am trying to create is getting a syntax error that I am unable to fix.  Unfortunately my lack of experience with python means I am struggling to know what to search for to find a solution.  I am also unsure how much code to include as I don't know exactly what is affecting it. If someone could link a jsfiddle style site for python I will include full code.

Python 2.7.6:

```
def click(event):
    across = int(c.canvasx(event.x / 200))
    down = int(c.canvasy(event.y / 200))

    square = across + (down * 3)

    if grid[square] == "X" or grid[square] == "O":
        return
    if winner():
        return

    if c.shape == "O":
        c.create_oval(
            across * 200, down * 200,
            (across + 1) * 200, (down + 1) * 200
        )
        grid[square] = "O"
        c.shape = "X"

    acrosstwo = int(randint(0,600)/200)
    downtwo = int(randint(0,600/200)          

    test = acrosstwo + (downtwo * 3)

    if grid[test] == "X" or grid[test] == "O":
        acrosstwo = int(randint(0,600)/200)
        downtwo = int(randint(0,600/200)

    else:
      c.create_line(
            acrosstwo * 200, downtwo * 200,
            (acrosstwo + 1) * 200, (downtwo + 1) * 200
        )
      c.create_line(
            acrosstwo * 200, (downtwo + 1) * 200,
            (acrosstwo + 1) * 200, downtwo * 200
        )

      grid[square] = "X"
      c.shape = "O"
```

The error I get when I run the program is "invalid syntax" and "test" is highlighted.
I presume I have made an error with how I am defining the variable?
The bit I don't understand is that the variable "square" works fine, and as far as I can see I have defined them in the same way.  I have tried different variable names as I'm not sure if test is a keyword in python.

if someone has already answered this question then I will happily remove the question.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually on the line before the definition of `test`:

```
downtwo = int(randint(0,600/200)
```

You need to add another `)` to the end of this line.

Comment: cheers, I really need to get better at spotting stupid things like that.